# Unable to run autocomplete with JSON input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI aocomplete component.
I have called an API call and feeding 'options' and 'value' with API response.
Following is the code.

// App.js

```
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

function App() {
  const [getUsers, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const fetchUsers = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      const userData = await response.json();
      setUsers(userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in catch!")
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, [fetchUsers]);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={getUsers.name} // should display dropdown options
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return <TextField {...params} />
      }}
      value={getUsers.id} // value for each dropdown item
    />
  )
}

export default App;
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `options` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(Autocomplete)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wiles-p0ozvk) link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop the `options` because you are retrieving an array, you can do that by using `map`

```
options={getUsers.map(el => el.name)}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
import { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

function App() {
  const [getUsers, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const fetchUsers = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
      );
      const userData = await response.json();
      // console.log("userData: ", userData);
      setUsers(userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in catch!");
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, [fetchUsers]);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={getUsers.map(el => el.name)}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return <TextField {...params} />;
      }}
      value={getUsers.id}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: why same map() is not used for value, like `value={getUsers.map(el => el.id)`
sandbox link don't have updated code.

Comment: `value={getUsers.map(el => el.id)` is creating errors 

MUI: The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned object (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) instead of a string for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. 

and displaying comma seperated ids as first option.


`value={getUsers.id}` is only working properly.

Comment: Issue is fixed.

Comment: Here is my sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-wiles-p0ozvk with 'value' code using map. (throwing errors) 
also, can you pls provide your sandbox link here once.

Comment: here is mine [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-montalcini-bygqk4), don't change mine, I see your changing mine

Comment: Thank you for your link as well. I see same Issue in console. I tried to put screenshot here, but on comments that facility is not there.
It is displaying 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 as first option, and also errors are coming in sandbox console.
Anyway, I am marking as resolved, as 'options' suggestion has fixed the Issue. But if you have some explanation for 'value' issue ie when map is used errors coming, then request you to explain.

Comment: sorry, will not change your sandbox, may be accidentally changed.

Comment: see the same sandbox with  no errors